# Poison Sumac or something else?

Tags: poisons

[image][image]I saw this growing out of a yard and onto the sidewalk. Is it Poison Sumac or non-poisonous Sumac? 11 leaflets, It has a smooth stem and leaflets so it is not Staghorn Sumac. I did not see any berries or fruit. Is there any of the poisonous kind around hear that I can see? Does It only grows in wetlands.

[image]

Comment: Where do you live? To me it seems much more to Ailanthus altissima.

Comment: I am in Northern Maryland. And I think you may be right. It does look like Ailanthus altissima. I think the poison sumac needs wetlands to survive.

Comment: Ailanthus , It will have a chiastic odor if you crush a some leaves  , which I think is unpleasant. Fast growing , relatively soft wood , relatively short life.

Comment: I haven't checked this post in a long time. Thanks for responding. I am in Rockville Maryland so this is Ailanthus altissima -  http://mdinvasives.org/iotm/sept-2007

Comment: @paulcap1 if you think my answer is right I'd love you to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first image is absolutely a *Wisteria spp.* leaflet--you can see the vine the leaves come from.

The second set of pictures is not *Ailanthus altissima*; it's missing the characteristic knob at the base of the leaflets (almost like the thumb on a mitten), and there is a gentle serration to the leaves (which is completely absent in *A. altissima*).

Absent photos of the stem, I'm inclined to say it's *Jugans nigra*, or black walnut. Key features that make me believe this is the way the leaflet 'starts' earlier on one side vs the other.

I know this is resurrecting a question, but I was tracking down images to confirm an ID for someone else and it struck me that the person was actually asking for ID's on two different plants.